# why airflow's webserver is exiting after filling up the Dagbag

Tags: airflow

I have been using airflow for a month without any such issues. But suddenly the webserver stopped working. It is exiting after filling up the DagBag. No errors are displayed either.

i even tried killing all the airflow and gunicorn processes. Still no luck.

This is what i see when executing "airflow webserver"

```
[uname@airflow airflow]$ airflow webserver
[2019-03-28 07:51:54,946] {settings.py:174} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800, pid=4128
[2019-03-28 07:51:55,356] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-03-28 07:51:55,459] {configuration.py:255} WARNING - section/key [rest_api_plugin/rest_api_plugin_http_token_header_name] not found in config
[2019-03-28 07:51:55,459] {configuration.py:255} WARNING - section/key [rest_api_plugin/rest_api_plugin_expected_http_token] not found in config
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/

[2019-03-28 07:51:55,705] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/uname/airflow/dags
[uname@airflow airflow]$
```

Comment: Try running with `logging_level` set to `DEBUG` to see if you can get more logs.

Comment: I figured the issue. I have put exit(1) somewhere in my code on a condition and so it exited the whole webserver while interpreting that code bit. Isn't that a bug? I just want my .py not to be loaded in the DagBag on some condition. How do i achieve that?

Comment: You could run your condition in your DAG file and have the .py file `return` early rather than doing exit(1). I haven't done this myself so not totally confident, but this should at least make sure the sys.exit(1) doesn't propagate up to the webserver. I thought this issue may have been resolved in a newer version of Airflow, so you can look into an update if you're not already on 1.10.x

Comment: I'm already using 1.10.2. anyway, I'll try "return" way. thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. In this case for me, this problem is caused by the default memory allocated for Docker. It is not enough for starting all of the services of Airflow. My solution is to allocate more memory for Docker, and that works for me.

> DockerDesktop > Setting > Resources > Advanced > Memory (Provide more memory here)

I hope this will help.